# uploading app to App Store produces faulty error message

Tags: ios, file-upload

In trying to upload my App to Apple it failed due to 'package does not contain a plist'. Well it does so this is not correct.The app runs without error on an attached iPad . This occurred after I changed the app display name (not the package name). Previously it uploaded without a problem.
 I have checked the plist and the package details (as suggested in a previous question) and can see nothing wrong or missing. I am stuck now as Apple support is closed for 2 weeks, so if you have a solution it would be very helpful to say the least.

Comment: `Bundle display name` is used for customize app name but `Bundle name` is used to identify your bundle, so please check whether you have changed `Bundle display name` or `Bundle name`

Comment: Yes, I only changed the display name not the bundle name which remains the same. I can't see mention of the display name in the package though but it appears correctly on my iPad test.